# Spatial filters not working after atomic updates

Tags: solr

I have a collection in apache solr cloud (version 9.2) which contain approx 4.3 million documents. Each document has approx 11 fields. Id, cityid, countyid, color, lastupdated, latlong, geometryrpt etc. Where is of type string and unique key, latlong field contain value like this ("40.54, -74.56") and geometryrpt feild is the copy field of latlong and of type location_rpt. Color field is stored=true and indexed=false. When i am doing updates on this collection using pysolr library using fieldsupdate={'color':'set'} and soft commit after every batch update Color values gets updated but my spatial queries( bbox or geofilter) return 0 result that were returning proper count before running atomic updates. When i update latlong field also along with color field then spatial query works fine. Is this any bug or i am missing something.

I have doubled checked the fields types of color and geometryrpt fields, data which i am updating, my query everthing. But everytime spatial query works fine before every update but stopped working after updates. I can see the updates color in the document but spatial queries returns 0.